# Prove $a\times2a\times3a\times...\times(p-1)a\equiv 1\times2\times3\times...\times(p-1) (\bmod p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and let $a$ be an integer not divisible by $p$. Then $$a\times2a\times3a\times...\times(p-1)a\equiv 1\times2\times3\times...\times(p-1) (\bmod p)$$

How do you approach this proof?

Comment: Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Not yet. I know this is the theorem that is used to help prove Fermat's Little Theorem though.

Comment: see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698275/prove-if-a-p-1-then-a-2a-3a-pa-is-a-complete-residue-system-modul

Comment: @Joshua Pepper: That would do it, but the lemma of the OP is intended as the main step in a *proof* of the Fermat Theorem.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, OP, this result is going to follow from your earlier question - the observation that $\{a, 2a, 3a, \ldots, (p-1)a\}$ is a rearrangement of $\{1,2,3,\ldots,(p-1)\}$.

Answer (score 6):

The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698275/prove-if-a-p-1-then-a-2a-3a-pa-is-a-complete-residue-system-modul) you asked recently asks one to show that $a,2a,3a,\dots,pa$ is a *complete* residue system modulo $p$. If we remove the $pa$, we get a reduced residue system. The numbers $a,2a,3a,\dots,(p-1)a$ are congruent, in some order, to $1,2,3,\dots,p-1$ modulo $p$.  It follows that their product $(a)(2a)\cdots((p-1)a)$ is congruent to $(1)(2)\cdots(p-1)$ modulo $p$.

**Concrete example:** Take $p=7$ and $a=2$. We look at $2,2\cdot 2, 3\cdot 2, \dots, 6\cdot 2$. These are congruent, modulo $7$, to $2,4,6,1,3,5$. These are just $1,2,3,4,5,6$ rearranged. So their product is congruent to $(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)$ modulo $7$.

Do in detail another concrete example, such as $a=4$ and $p=11$, and you will fully understand what's happening.

Comment: Why is necessary to remove $pa$ to get a reduced residue system?

Comment: $pa$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $p$. A reduced residue system modulo $p$ consists of any set $S$ of $p-1$ numbers, such that any of $,2,3,\dots,p-1$ is congruent to exactly one element of $S$.