# Covering systems for integers vs. natural numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A [covering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system) is a set of congruences $\{a_1 \mod n_1, \dots a_k \mod n_k\}$ covering $\mathbb{Z}$. The Mirsky-Newman theorem says that a covering system cannot cover disjoint sets and have distinct moduli. The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237909/understanding-a-proof-of-the-davenport-rado-mirsky-newman-theorem) seems to assume we cover only the natural numbers. Why is this? Is it obvious that a congruence system covers $\mathbb{Z}$ iff it covers $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true that a congruence system that covers the naturals necessarily covers the integers. E.g., $0\bmod2,1\bmod4,3\bmod8,7\bmod{16},\dots$ covers the naturals but not $-1$. But a finite congruence system that covers the naturals must cover the integers. Let $m$ be the least common multiple of the moduli, then the whole shebang is periodic mod $m$, so if it covers everything from $1$ to $m$, it covers everything.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the finite set of natural numbers under mod $n$ $$\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$$

I think it is sufficient if we show that above set is congruent to the set
$$\{-0,-1,-2,\ldots,-(n-1)\}$$
in some order.

Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698275/prove-if-a-p-1-then-a-2a-3a-pa-is-a-complete-residue-system-modul)theorem